# How can I extend the EF Repository Model to do more complex queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have the following:

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public Subject()
    {
        this.Contents = new List<Content>(); 
    }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public partial class Content
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

In my SQL Server database I have an index on the Content table of SubectId and ContentTypeId

My classes are working find with a standard repository that has such methods such as GetAll() and GetId(id) however using the repository model is there a way I can do more complex queries. In this case I would somehow want todo a query for a particular SujectId and a contentTypeId. What I want to avoid is having a query that gets every content record and then filters out what I need. I'd like some way to send a real query of exactly what I need to SQL Server.

Currently my generic repository has the following:

```
    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

Could I do what I need by implementing creating a ContentRepository and having something like the following:

```
    public IQuerable<Content> GetAllBySubjectId(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(c => c.SubjectId == id);
    }
```

If so then how could I use the GetAllBySubjectId and add in the check for where ContentId == "01" for example?

Comment: Usage of [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) will result in sending real queries to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to your repository a method like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DbSet.Where<T>(predicate);
}
```

Then write sth like:

```
repository.Find(c => c.SubjectId == myId);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have another question about how to put a service layer in between but for now I will mark this as accepted and then ask that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework with LINQ, it will try to generate and send optimized queries to the database, for example, if you do something like:

```
var contents = 
    from c in Context.Contents  //  or directly the DbSet of Contents
    where c.ContentTypeId == 2
    select new { c.Title, c.ContentId };
```

It should generate a query along the lines of the following (you can use a SQL Profiler):

```
    select 
        c.Title as Title,
        c.ContentId as ContentId
    from Contents c
    where
        c.ContentTypeId == 2
```

There are some considerations to think of, but most of the time EF will generate good performance queries.
To know more about that, I recommend the following URL: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/entity-framework-performance-optimization/